# React - how to populate one select menu based on a value of another select menu using data from a local .json file

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I try to change the content of select menu "Object subtype" based on the value of the select menu "Object type" using data from a local .json file in React v16

E.g.: 
If I select a plant in the select menu "Object type", then it shows Aloe, Cactus and Rose in the select menu "Object subtype".

I have a `data.json`

```
{
  "object": [
    {
      "objectType": "Plant",
      "objectSubtype": ["Aloe","Cactus","Rose"]
    },
    {
      "objectType": "Animal",
      "objectSubtype": ["Cat","Dog","Dolphin"]
    },
    {
      "objectType": "Stone",
      "objectSubtype": ["Granite","Marble","Travertine"]
    }
  ]
}
```

and I have `Object.js`

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Object extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      objectType: "",
      objectSubtype: ""
    };
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
  }
  onChange(e) {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form>
        <div className="form-group">
          <select
            id="objectType"
            multiple={false}
            className="form-control"
            value={this.state.objectType}
            onChange={this.onChange}
          >
            <option>Select an object type</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">
          <select
            id="objectSubtype"
            multiple={false}
            className="form-control"
            value={this.state.objectSubtype}
            onChange={this.onChange}
          >
            <option>Select an object subtype</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
export default Object;
```

My goal is to populate both select menus and populate the second select menu "Object subtype" based on the value from the select menu "Object type" using data from a local file data.json. How is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first Select "objectType" set the option like

```
let objectOption = []
data.object.forEach(x=>objectOption.push(x.objectType))
```

and loop over this for the first select Options.
on change of the value from this select you need to set your second state variable i.e, objectSubtype

For that you can pass onChangeHandler to your first Select and set the second state as well from here.

```
onObjectChange = (value) => {
  // TODO: handle for null value as well
  let subTypeValue = data.object.filter(x=>x.objectType===value)[0].objectSubtype
  this.setState({objectType:value, objectSubtype:subTypeValue})
}
```

and your second Select can have its own onChangeHandler, which can be simple like

```
onSubObjectChange = (value) => {
  this.setState({objectSubtype:value})
}
```

Comment: Loading objectTypes from local file data.json to the first select menu works, therefore Plant, Animal, and Stone in the first select menu are provided. After I click one of this item and onObjectChange method is called, it throws me an error message  `"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'objectSubtype' of "undefined"`, when it iterates up to the last element.

Comment: @Bronle It is because `data.object.filter(x=>x.objectType===value)[0]` is not returning anything. So you can check what is the value of `"value"` variable. try adding `console.log(value)` as a first line in onObjectChange function. You will get it.

Comment: Thank you @Rinkesh, it has helped me.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same onChange for two differents dropdowns.
You should only use your current onChange for the first select, do your things there, and then

`this.setState(objectSubtype: myCustomData);`

And as your state will be updated, the second select now it will have your info